# How to do you load a model from a checkpoint using simple transformers?

Tags: python, simpletransformers

I am using the simple transformers library, I have just finished training a model and now I want to load it to try making some predictions. However, I must be doing something wrong because it keeps raising an error. Here is my code:

```
from simpletransformers.seq2seq import Seq2SeqModel
model = Seq2SeqModel("marian","outputs/best_model")
print(model)

print(model.predict(["Using AI to Accelerate Scientific Discovery"]))
```

Here is the error it displays:

```
ValueError: You must specify a Seq2Seq config    OR     encoder_type, encoder_name, and decoder_name OR                 encoder_type and encoder_decoder_name
```

I have tried to search up answers from the documentation but I couldn't find anything.